# Problem when using process.cwd() in published npm package

Tags: node.js, git

I'm dipping my toes into cli tooling by building a simple program for automating Gerrit commits. Everything works locally, but after publishing the package to npm and installing it globally it looks like `process.cwd()` behaves differently. The program exits, but no `console.log()`. Even a simple `console.log(process.cwd())` is ignored (again works locally). Is it possible to use `process.cwd()` when running a globally installed npm package?

```
console.log(process.cwd());

const getCurrentBranchName = (p = process.cwd()) => {
  const gitHeadPath = `${p}/.git/HEAD`;

  return fs.existsSync(gitHeadPath)
    ? fs.readFileSync(gitHeadPath, "utf-8").trim().split("/").pop()
    : (console.log("not a git repo"), process.exit(0));
}

const currentBranch = getCurrentBranchName();
```

When ran locally (with `node index`):

```
$ /Users/jpap/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/gittest
$ not a git repo
```

Comment: So the code you're showing is in a file that is installed as a CLI tool (using the [`bin` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) in `package.json`)? What's the executable called?

Comment: Yes, and it runs. If in a git repo it works, if not it just exits without logging.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, with that code (missing pieces like shebang line and `require('fs')` added) it's working fine as a globally installed executable for me.

Comment: Karl, can you confirm that the problem is not `console.log` calls? See the first part of my answer.  @robertklep I suspect that the code published to npm is not the same as above, per my answer. Also pinning the blame on process.cwd() seems to be an unproven assumption.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I just had to await the function that checks the current branch. When executed with `node index` everything worked, but when executing the globally installed package the check must have "run slower". Still have no idea why the first console.log() did nothing (well it was just for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

### You haven't proved the problem is with `process.cwd()`

The code in your question and the results your describe only indicate that the `console.log()` calls aren't executing.

You could easily test this by adding the following to the top of your code:

```
console.log('My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die!')
```

### What you are publishing is likely not the same as what you are running locally

For example, you could be using a bundler (e.g. Rollup) configured to strip console.log calls.

This is easy to confirm. Simple look at the code of the npm installed version:

1. Use `npm root -g` to find out where your global packages are installed. For non-global packages, look in `node_modules`.
2. Find your package's subdir.
3. Look at the code, or diff it with the source code.

I suspect you will see all console.log statements removed.

Comment: If OP is talking about CLI tooling, I don't think they'd use rollup or another bundler.

Comment: @AKX Perhaps. But that's an assumption too. They could be using a standard project template at their job, or copied and existing project and replaced the code. Regardless, Occam's Razor: evidence points to it being `console.log` not `process.cwd`, and I know it is fairly common to strip console.log from published code. I can't think of any other likely reason that console.log calls fail/are ignored. The other likely possibility is operator error; i.e. we don't have all the info.